# How can I reveal a client's IP address in an SSL trace on JVM?

Tags: java, ssl, jvm

I have a Java server and it's being pounded by connections from a client over SSL, but according to the logs, it looks like the client doesn't trust our server's certificate:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:192)
    at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:154)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.recvAlert(SSLSocketImpl.java:2023)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1125)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1375)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1403)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1387)
```

We have no idea which client is causing this and there are just way too many to check, some of them are even on remote environments that we don't have access to. Enabling the javax.net.debug=all JVM parameter doesn't give me any clues on which client is establishing the connection.

Is anyone aware of an additional JVM argument (Oracle JDK) that I can use which will give additional information on the IP addresses/hostnames of the clients establishing SSL connections?

If not, any ideas on how I may go about this to find out who the client is? I was thinking of gathering TCP/IP packets and try to find incomplete SSL handshakes that were terminated right after the serverHello message for example.

Answer (score 0):

You might increase the log level of the HTTP server to see more details about this but my quickest solution with this is to start Wireshark or some other packet sniffing tool. It's much easier to read and you don't need to restart the JVM each time you want to change the `javax.net.debug` system property.

Answer (score 0):

If the client is calling a web service, this may be useful:

```
@Resource
WebServiceContext wsContext;

HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest)wsContext.getMessageContext().get(SOAPMessageContext.SERVLET_REQUEST); 
String remoteIp = request.getRemoteAddr();
String remoteUser = request.getRemoteUser();
String remoteHost = request.getRemoteHost();

l.debug(String.format("Client - Remote IP address: %s, Remote User: %s, Remote Host: %s", remoteIp, remoteUser, remoteHost));
```

Comment: Not really. The error happens during the TLS handshake so you never reach the part, where HTTP comes into place, i.e. requesting a URL and invoking a servlet.